# MySQL Select Date Equal to Today (having datetime as the data type)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a mysql select statement where it looks at today's date and only returns results that signed up on that current day. I've currently tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    FROM users 
    WHERE users.signup_date = CURDATE()
```

I've modified my `SELECT` statement to this, thanks guys.

`SELECT id FROM users WHERE DATE(signup_date) = CURDATE()`

Comment: it seems that `signup_date` is datetime field

Comment: @Serjio Yes, it currently is a datetime field.

Comment: what is the datatype of `signup_date` if it contains the time, then you will want to use the date_format in the `WHERE` clause to strip the time to match the `CURDATE()`

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, I've modified my script. It seems to work, but when there are no results. `mysql_num_rows` doesn't display 0. Just a blank.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE(signup_date) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: is it necessary to use DATE()  even the field is type Date ?

Comment: @rashidnk No. Although he didn't say clearly in the question, the field is apparently of type `DATETIME`.

Comment: While this solution is absolutely correct, it does not scale well (cannot use an index on `signup_date`, even if such an index exists). Prefer [Serjio's  solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12677822/1446005).

Comment: or if to find on a particular date, with the index also being utilised ```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM users where signup_date >= '2017-08-30 00:00:00' and signup_date <=  '2017-08-30 23:59:59' ;
```

Comment: @SumitMAsok Better to use `< '2017-08-31 00:00:00'` in case you're using a version of MySQL with milliseconds.

Comment: benchmarking CURDATE() vs DATE( NOW() ) and seems like DATE( NOW() ) is faster by approximately 10% on average

Answer (score 45):

This query will use index if you have it for `signup_date` field

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
    FROM users 
    WHERE signup_date >= CURDATE() && signup_date < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Downvotes to this answer are absurd. This is in fact the prefered approach, because this query would be able to leverage an index on `signup_date`, unlike other approaches.

Comment: @RandomSeed The general idea of testing for `signup_date` between two times is correct, but the times are not. It should be between `00:00` and `23:59:59` on the current date.

Comment: Well the date interval was wrong too >.< The downvotes were not that absurd after all.

Comment: This query is way more performant (due to the index). The `WHERE DATE(signup_date) = CURDATE()` took my server ~50 ms, this one here 0.8 ms.

Answer (score 19):

Sounds like you need to add the formatting to the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce623/2)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CONCAT` with `CURDATE()` to the entire time of the day and then filter by using the `BETWEEN` in `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM users 
WHERE (users.signup_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 23:59:59'))
```

Comment: by far the most performant method.. not even comparable when running on large data sets. Multiple orders of magnitude faster. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple code to find date

```
SELECT users.id, DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
FROM users 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(users.signup_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE()
```

Comment: I've edited out the link to your answer that you posted on another site, as it's not relevant to this post. In the future, when linking to external content, make sure it's relevant, and especially make sure to disclose any affiliation. If you don't do so you can be considered a spammer. Please see [this](/help/promotion) for more details.