# sql query to fetch the records of next 30 days

Tags: mysql

Here is my problem, I want to fetch next 30 days records from the table. I have a field in my table. For ex: In my table  I have `resource_date`, In this column I have many records from `2013-02-05` to `2015-10-10`. Say, If I logged into the website today(Today's Date is- `16/01/2015`, It should fetch record for next 15 days and so on). How to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: What type of field is `resource_date`?  Is it a `DATETIME` field?

Comment: @Leo . Yes Mysql. Yes It's a DATETIME field

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677707/mysql-select-date-equal-to-today

You can set the date format as well..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE resource_date >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY -- skip today
   AND resource_date < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 17 DAY -- 15 days starting tomorrow
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9f8f83/1)** demo

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can use the `NOW()` function to get the current `DATETIME`, and the `INTERVAL` keyword to get intervals of time.

So, to get the records where `resource_date` is within the next 30 days, you would use:

```
SELECT *
 FROM `my_table_name`
WHERE `resource_date` >= NOW()
  AND `resource_date` < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
    ;
```

In practice, you should rarely use `SELECT *`, and you should consider adding a `LIMIT` to this query to prevent your application from returning a result set that is "too large".

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to hit the "Accept" checkmark if this answer solves the problem.

Comment: @YogeshNaik FYI If you need your result set from 0am till 12pm this query is no good because it may leave some leading rows and grab extra trailing ones.

Comment: @peterm. Yes but I traced it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

```
...
WHERE
'resource_date'> NOW() AND
'resource_date'< DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 31 DAY);
```

Careful I think now() does minutes and hours so you miss a portion of a day.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE resource_date >= CURDATE() AND resource_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), interval 15 DAY)
```