# Mixed sorting of dates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date column which holds either a date value or null. I use that to hold a product's expiration date. I want to write a query to fetch them in this order: Not yet expired, no expiration (null), and expired.

For example, assuming today is May 15:

```
prd_id   prd_name   Expiry Date
-----------------
1    name1         May 16
2    name2         May 17
3    name3         May 18
4    name4         May 21
5    namex         null
6    namex         null
7    namex         null
8    namex         May 14
9    namex         May 12
```

*(A null value denotes no expiration)*

How would I do this?

Comment: If it is a date column mysql will order the dates correctly. Just use ```order by date```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @AgeDeO php will sort them asc or desc but what i need is combination of them please check the sampple

Comment: Provide your table definition and some sample data set

Comment: @sgtBOSE Yeah i couldn't get the combination of asc and desc . As of now i am fetching and sorting them in php. I am looking for only mysql solution.

Comment: Than add the code also.

Comment: this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677707/mysql-select-date-equal-to-today

Answer (score 1):

You can try follwing Syntax:-

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY CASE WHEN expire_date > CURDATE() THEN 1 END,
WHEN expire_date IS NULL THEN 2 Desc END,
WHEN expire_date < CURDATE() THEN 3 Desc END;
```

Comment: i have few doubts here 1) what is case in order by "case"  2)  where is asc sorting done when  expire_date > CURDATE() and desc in other condition

Comment: Case applies a Just a condin order by clause. And for Asc and Desc see mu edit now

Comment: Careful! There are three problems I see: testing for null must be done using either [IS NULL or IS NOT NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) instead of just using =, < or >, you need to handle the case when the expiry date is the current date, and the query [doesn't actually work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g7i7X.png)

Comment: @ChrisForrence, your NULL point is accepted. And corrected and rest i think is correct.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - I do suggest setting up a table for testing; the NULL check wasn't the issue that I raised in my third point; it's your use of the CASE statement.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I am having syntax error when i am running this query

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you'll be joining three separate queries together:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `product_entries` WHERE expires_on IS NOT NULL AND expires_on > CURDATE()
    ORDER BY expires_on ASC) a
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `product_entries` WHERE expires_on IS NULL) b
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `product_entries` WHERE expires_on IS NOT NULL AND expires_on <= CURDATE() 
    ORDER BY expires_on DESC) c
```

The first one returns those that haven't expired, the second returns those without expiration, and the third one returns expired entries.

Keep in mind that you'd want the `expires_on` column to be indexed. Also, as you can see in the third query, I'm counting the current date as being expired. If you want the current day to count as not being expired, then change the `<=` to `<` in the third query, and `>` to `>=` in the first query.

---

Another alternative would to be to use a CASE clause (if you're not concerned about the order of each entry, so long as the non-expired are at the top, the perpetual products are in the middle, and the expired entries are at the bottom)

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM product_entries ORDER BY CASE 
    ->     WHEN expires_on >= CURDATE() THEN 3
    ->     WHEN expires_on IS NULL THEN 2
    ->     WHEN expires_on < CURDATE() THEN 1
    -> END DESC;

+----+-------------+
| id | expire_date |
+----+-------------+
|  9 | 2015-05-11  |
|  8 | 2015-05-06  |
|  7 | 2015-05-01  |
| 10 | NULL        |
|  6 | 2015-04-26  |
|  5 | 2015-04-21  |
|  4 | 2015-04-16  |
|  3 | 2015-04-11  |
|  2 | 2015-04-06  |
|  1 | 2015-04-01  |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: There was a tiny issue with my original query having to do with UNION and ORDER BY; this has been fixed.

Comment: Wat do you think?? Is this query optimised?? Or Is this the correct logic??

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Is it as efficient as it possibly can? No. It is, however, clear, and more importantly, it works.

Comment: Only working is not the correct solution with logic. In programming field you have to be specific and optimized for better throughput and result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - Nope; first is getting it correct, then optimizing. Are you absolutely sure your query actually works? Have you tried running it?

Comment: Yes i m pretty sure that it will work. Thats y i m emphasising on using my query over yours. Though you are also not wrong, but still better logic gives better result.