# SQL PHP - How to get records of specific day by timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL database that has a column "A" that has timestamps in it.

How do I return all values that have a timestamp that doesnt fall under the current day. So say for example its Monday, i want to return all values that are not this Monday.
[image]

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Which database provider is relevant to the question you're asking?

Comment: It is MYSQL hosted on PHPMYADMIN

Comment: In this example, would you filter out all dates that fall on *any* Monday (like, seven days ago), or just today?

Comment: I would just like to filter out the day the query is run.

Comment: Beware, the naive solution does not scale. Prefer [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12677822/1446005).

Comment: @Randomseed why is that solution more scalable? As some of the rows im retrieving will have NULL values in it. So isn't the IFNULL a must? As you cannot compare a date to a NULL value? In this case when there is a value that isn't the current date and its null I'm grabbing it.

Comment: The accepted answer relies on a function call on a table column (`WHERE DATE(emailsend) ...`). Such queries are unable to use an index on this column, even if such an index exists (the values `emailsend` would be indexed, not the result of `DATE(emailsend)`).

Comment: @Randomseed so the only way to optimise this query would be to separate the date and time columns instead of having them in the same column? Also I am using this query right now select * from table where IFNULL(DATE(emailsend),'0000-00-00') !=CURDATE()  And I can see what you mean as every row it is grabbing the date and working out whether it's NULL or not which is heavy.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with NULL values. `WHERE any_function(col) = 'whatever'` => cannot use an index on `col`. `WHERE col = any_function('whatever')` => can use an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **DATE()** or **CURDATE()** MySQL function:-

Return all values that are **current date** :-

```
select * from table where DATE(emailsend)=CURDATE()
```

Return all values that are **not current date** :-

```
select * from table where DATE(emailsend) !=CURDATE()
```

> Or use MySQL WEEKDAY() returns the index of the day in a week for a
>   given date (**0 for Monday**, 1 for Tuesday and ......6 for Sunday)

```
select * from table where WEEKDAY(emailsend) !=0
//Return all values where day not is monday
```

Comment: That's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @Rahauto My timestamp has null values in it when an email isn't sent so the query isn't returning all the values. I know a solution is to also look for NULL values but do you think I should change the default of the column so that it has a default of 0000-00-00 when the email has not been sent so it works with the query you have given me?

Comment: Just to clarify the column is set to default to NULL when the column has not been filled.

Comment: Use MySQL function **IFNULL(emailsend,'0000-00-00')** @Code

Comment: @Rahautos How would I use that with select * from table where DATE(emailsend) !=CURDATE() ?

Comment: select * from table where IFNULL(DATE(emailsend),'0000-00-00') !=CURDATE() @Code

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way I see to do this is to ignore the time and compare only dates with date() function.

```
select * from table where date(A) != date(now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Rahautos answer, you can do

```
select * from table where WEEKDAY(emailsend) !=WEEKDAY(now());
```

Then it should select all the weekdays except for current weekday. Not tested, but it sounds right to me.