# mysql where date is on Monday

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query MySQL database all the record where date is on Monday or Tuesday like query would be

```
select count(*) from table where date = Monday;
```

what would be best way to execute that query in mysql workbench

thanks

Comment: You can find the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216559/sql-php-how-to-get-records-of-specific-day-by-timestamp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try function `weekday`:

```
select count(*) from table where weekday(date) = 0;
```

And see official [**doc**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) here.

As @[**Psi**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7607970/psi) said, if you will concern performance, you should avoid function, and you'd better create a new column to store weeday.

Comment: That will work (therefor the upvote) but be aware that a possible index that has been set to `\`date\`` will not work in that case

Comment: @Psi Hmm, u're right. If `date` is index and if there is big data. I think op should add a new column to store weekday.

Comment: That's what I would suggest in that case