# consulting database when data is today, tomorrow, after tomorrow

Tags: php, mysql

I need to consult a table using mysql...for today, tomorrow, after tomorrow,..

by now I use the following code where data is the day in format YYYY-MM-DD

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * from `Meteo` where `data` >= "2017-03-31" ');
```

what should I insert in where `data` >= in order to get the data for today, tomorrow...without inserting manually the date?

Comment: [`now()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Date Equal to Today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677707/mysql-select-date-equal-to-today)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can it easy calculate with:

```
SELECT DATE (NOW()  + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT DATE (NOW()  + INTERVAL 1 DAY) as result;
+------------+
| result     |
+------------+
| 2017-03-30 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get tomorrow's date:

```
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 1 day"))
```

Now you can add that variable to your query:

```
$data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * from `Meteo` where `data` >= "'.$tomorrow.'" ');
```

Then you can simply add more days as needed:

```
$after_tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+ 2 day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$DTtoday = new DateTime(); //Current date
$DT2days = clone $DTtoday; //Create new object from $DTtoday
$DT2days->add(new DateInterval("P2D")); //Add 2 days
$data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * from `Meteo` where `data` BETWEEN "'.$DTtoday->format("Y-m-d").'" AND "'.$DT2days->format("Y-m-d").'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use now() 
and between interval 2 days

```
 data_query = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'select * 
              from `Meteo` 
              where `data` between now() and date_add(date(now() ), interval 2 day)) ;
```