# This query is displaying data of yesterday and today also but i want only today's data

Tags: mysql

sql query showing data for today and yesterday but i want data for current date only

```
select * from branches
where NOT EXISTS
(
    select * 
    from mytable 
    where mytable.branch_code = branches.Branch_Code 
      and mytable.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURDATE()
)
```

getting data for current date and yestarday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select Date Equal to Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677707/mysql-select-date-equal-to-today)

Comment: You specifically asked for date between yesterday and today instead of just on today... See the link above for the required syntax