# Order by today date on datatable

Tags: mysql, json, ajax, datatable

Is there anyway to order datatable, which has a date column and using server-side by ajax data, by today date first and the others rows order by date asc?

I know how to order by date column ASC or DESC.. but how can I do today first and then ASC

hope anyone could help me

Comment: search for mysql order by case

Comment: Other questions with more [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+order+by+with+case+statement+site%253Astackoverflow.com). You can also look at [MySQL Select Date Equal to Today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12677707/12567365) for that piece of the solution.